# how to flag in pandas dataframe if the number is in a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe, flags

I have a pandas data frame consisting of some numbers
[image: my data]

And i have a list containing some elements of the data frame.how can i add a flag 1 if the element in pd data frame is in my list

Answer (score 0):

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "col" : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],
})
```

flag

```
li = [1,2,3]

df.loc[df.col.isin(li), "flag"] = 1
```

result

```
    col flag
0   1   1.0
1   2   1.0
2   3   1.0
3   4   NaN
4   5   NaN
5   6   NaN
6   7   NaN
7   8   NaN
```